# Why aren't the array objects changing when changed in the JFrame they were added to?

Tags: java, arrays

I am adding an array of objects onto a JFrame. When I change the object's state in the JFrame, it is not changing in the array. The object's class is called *connect2*. The change that I am making is increasing connect2's arrayPosition field by 1. The change is made on the object that was added to the JFrame, but not the corresponding array.

The algorithm is as follows:

*connect1* extends JFrame and contains the main method which invokes the *connect1* constructor. The connect1 constructor set the size for the JFrame, set the JFrame to visible, set a GridLayout, and instantiates 100 connect2 objects which are also JPanels and adds them to an array. The 100 connect2 JPanels are added to the JFrame via for loop.

The *connect2* constructor takes in a connect1 argument. When *connect2* is clicked, it will increment connect1's static counter field. The counter's value is passed to connect2's arrayposition variable.

For some reason when I access the connect2 object in the array in *connect1*, the arrayposition variable has not changed.

Can someone please give me a hand with this issue? Why aren't the objects in the array changing as well. Java arrays store the memory locations of the objects, don't they?

Here is my code:

```
package connect;

import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class connect1 extends JFrame 
{
static int counter = 0;     
int M = 10;
int N = 10;
int Grid = M*N;
connect2 array[] = new connect2 [Grid];

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    new connect1();
}

public connect1()
{
    setVisible(true);
    setSize(1000, 1000);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setLayout(new GridLayout(M, N));
    //add(new Welcome(this));
    //int Grid = M*N;
    //connect2 array[] = new connect2 [Grid];
    for (int j = 0; j < Grid; j++)
    {
        array[j] = new connect2(this);
        add(array[j]);
    }
}

public void toRefresh()
{
    if (counter > 0)
    {
        bubbleSort(array);
    }

    repaint();
}

public void bubbleSort(connect2[] x)
{
    connect2 temp;
    for (int i = 0; i < /*x.length*/ counter - 1; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 1; j < /*x.length*/ counter - i; j++)
        {
            //System.out.println(x[j - 1].arrayPosition+" j - 1 "+x[j].arrayPosition+" j ");
            if (x[j - 1].arrayPosition > x[j].arrayPosition)
            {
                temp = x[j - 1];
                x[j - 1] = x[j];
                x[j] = temp;
            }

        }
    }
}

public void undo()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
    {
        System.out.println(array[i].arrayPosition);
    }
}

}
```

Connect2 class:

```
package connect;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import javax.swing.JPanel;


public class connect2 extends JPanel
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

int arrayPosition;
int whenClicked = 0;
connect1 refr = null;


public connect2(connect1 refresh)
{
    addMouseListener(new MouseListener()
    {

        @SuppressWarnings("static-access")
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) 
        {
            if(arg0.getModifiers() == MouseEvent.BUTTON1_MASK)
            {
                whenClicked++;
                refr.counter++;
                arrayPosition = refr.counter;
                refr.toRefresh();
            }

            if(arg0.getModifiers() == MouseEvent.BUTTON3_MASK)
            {
                System.out.println(arrayPosition);
                refr.undo();                
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent arg0) 
        {
            // Not used 
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent arg0)
        {
            // Not used     
        }

        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent arg0) 
        {
            // Not used     
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent arg0)
        {
            // Not used     
        }

    });

    refr = refresh;
}

@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{
    switch(whenClicked)
    {
      case 1:
        g.setColor(Color.red);
        break;

      case 2:
        g.setColor(Color.blue);
        break;
    }
        g.fillOval(0, 0, 80, 80);
}


}
```

Comment: the same object is both in the frame and array, so it is updated. What input are you giving, and what output do you expect?

Comment: vandale, I am going to revise my question to detail my input.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the refr = refresh; statement. This statement is located below arrayPosition = refr.counter.